# Why is Show Tables a better option over DatabaseMetaData.getTables() when looking for a specific table in a database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I currently have a method in my Java program, using JDBC that checks if a specific table exists in a MySQL database. I had a logic error where the DatabaseMetaData.getTables() method was returning a same-named table from a different database, and I've now solved that by specifying the catalog in the statement as seen below (table represents the table name I'm looking for).

```
    ResultSet tables = connectionToDatabase().getMetaData().getTables("snakeandladder", null, table, null);
```

However, after doing some research, I saw a lot of people recommending to use Show Tables instead, but not actually explaining why to use Show tables over the above.
Can someone explain to me the limitations of using the statement above and why Show Tables would be a better option?
Thank you!

Comment: I think what is better depends on perspective and opinion. Using the JDBC API in general is better for portability, but sometimes it doesn't provide all information that the database system itself has available. As to your initial problem, that is a matter of not reading the documentation properly. If you don't qualify the catalog or schema, then JDBC will look in all available catalogs and schemas, but it would have returned all occurrences. BTW: you might want to link to those "[recommendations[ to use show tables instead", so that we can understand the context.

Answer (score 0):

DatabaseMetaData.getTables() is more portable, most of the databases (not only MySQL) should be able to provide information through defined API.

On the other hand using MySQL specific query "show tables;" may cause more harm than good:

- you introduce a query string which can be exploited by an attacker, also the code now contains a statically compiled query string.
- if ever the database provider will change, so the code will have to be updated (again portability)